# Nginx Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, webserver

Hi I'm trying to move my old dev environment to a new machine. However I keep getting "bad gateway errors" from nginx. From nginx's errorlog:

```
*19 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ~(?<app>[^.]+).gp2, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "backend.gp2:5555"
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out that PHP-fpm was not running

Answer (score 6):

Looks like your upstream host at 127.0.0.1:9000 is not accepting connections. Is the upstream process working?

Comment: Not sure how/where should I check? Thanks!

Comment: Essentially - nginx is looking for an upstream fastcgi process listening on post 9000 of localhost. Either you haven't started that process on the new box, or it isn't listening. What should be running at that port?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have nginx configured as a proxy, that tries to proxy its requests to localhost on port 9000, but cannot find anything listening on port 9000.

Answer (score 1):

In my workstation, running `php` works for me. Take note that I'm using PHP 7.4 in my Mac. Pls adjust the PHP version according to what is installed in your workstation.

Working command:

`sudo brew services start php@7.4`

Answer (score 0):

Please start your varnish:
sudo varnishd -a 127.0.0.1:80 -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -f /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl -s file,/tmp,500M